# Can not find the declaration of element 'persistence' (Eclipselink and HibernateOGM together)

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, hibernate-ogm

I'm struggling with this problem in days.
This code is part of a big project obviously I cannot post it all.
I get this error when I instanciate a `MyObj` object and try to make it persistent in Mysql (first persistence unit) and mongodb (second persistence unit).
Searching around this error seems caused to a JPA incompatibility somewhere.

persistence.xml (with 2 PUs)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="MYSQLPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
        <class>com.jpa.MyObj</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldev" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
     <persistence-unit name="MONGOPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
        <class>com.jpa.MyObj</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="com.arjuna.ats.jta.jtaTMImplementation"
                value="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple" />
            <property name="com.arjuna.ats.jta.jtaUTImplementation"
                value="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.UserTransactionImple" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider"
                value="mongodb" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database"
                value="ActingMongo" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host"
                value="127.0.0.1" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port" value="27017" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

main class

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;

public class CreateMyObj {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //some proprietary objects
        PlatConfiguration configuration = new PlatConfiguration();
        Plat.init(configuration, DataManager.getInstance());

        MyObj me = new MyObj();
        me.setTitle("MyObj  title");
        me.setType("MyObj");
        me.setUserId(0);


        /*--------------------mysql persistence managed using some external proprietary libs ----------------------------*/
        try {
            DataManager.getInstance().save(me); //this object instanciates the EntityManagerFactory and the EntityManager and make the object persistent

            System.out.println("persistence successful");
        } catch (DataManagerException e) {
            System.out.println("persistence unsuccessful!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /*----------------------mongodb persistence -------------------*/
        //the following line throw the exception
EntityManagerFactory emfactory2 = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MONGOPU");
        EntityManager entitymanager2 = emfactory2.createEntityManager();

         javax.transaction.TransactionManager tx = com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();
            try {
                tx.begin();
                entitymanager2.joinTransaction();
                entitymanager2.persist(me);
                tx.commit();
                log.log(Level.INFO, "no sql Persist successful...");
            } catch (Exception re) {
                try {
                    tx.rollback();
                } catch (IllegalStateException | SecurityException | SystemException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "no sql Persist failed...", re);
                //throw re;
            } finally {
                if (entitymanager2 != null) {
                    entitymanager2.clear();
                    entitymanager2.close();
                }
            }

    }

}
```

This is the complete stacktrace that shows the error comes from Hibernate and not eclipselink

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-elt.1: impossibile trovare la dichiarazione dell'elemento "persistence".

    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.validate(PersistenceXmlParser.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:46)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.helloproject.jpa.CreateMyObj.main(CreateMyObj.java:57)
```

Comment: Hibernate OGM is supposed to be used with Hibernate ORM, I'm not familiar with EclipseLink but I don't think you can use the two together

Comment: I already tried with a simpler project in which I use eclipselink with mysql PU and hibernate ogm for the mongodb PU..all works fine. This is a big project and I cannot detect which module incompatibility causes the error

Comment: If you get an exception then you can see where the exception coems from by looking at its stack trace. But we dont see what it is. Also I don't get the comment "Hibernate OGM is supposed to be used with Hibernate ORM" ... the JPA spec is very clear in allowing multiple JPA providers to be used alongside each other

Comment: @Billy Frost thank you. I was not sure about the COMPLETE legit of using eclipselink and hibernate ogm, now I'm sure this is not an issue :). As I said the error is thrown when I try to instanciate the 2nd PU EntityManagerFactory (the mongodb one). I edited the question with the complete stacktrace

Comment: It's only complaining about the overall format of the XML fiel relative to the XSD ... i.e not specific to your MongoDB unit. Maybe that version of "Hibernate OGM" requires JPA 2.2 and doesn't allow JPA 2.1 validation? Search in its docs and see if you can turn OFF `persistence.xml` validation. The JPA provider I use (DataNucleus JPA) allows such things to be turned off

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following header for the persistence.xml?

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"                                         
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                           
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. It looks like the schemas moved.